# converting html to text with perl

Tags: perl, cpan

I have a bunch of html files and need to convert and format them to text with perl i.e somthing like `<br/>` will be interperted to `\n`

I found this perl module on cpan html::formattext it format the text well but if there is link it strip it ,
are there any option with [HTML::FormatText](http://p3rl.org/HTML%3a%3aFormatText) to format the html as is to text but when 
there  links like this

```
<a href="http://www.microsoft.com>http://www.microsoft.com</a>
```

i.e somthing like this :

```
<br /><b>Microsoft</b><br /><a href="http://www.microsoft.com>`
```

will be converted to:

```
microsoft
http://www.microsoft.com
```

Comment: I always use *lynx* to do this, because I’ve never found anything better. I would love to, though.

Comment: If you already have `lynx` installed, there's [`HTML::FormatText::Lynx`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?HTML::FormatText::Lynx)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a look at [HTML::FormatText::WithLinks](http://search.cpan.org/~struan/HTML-FormatText-WithLinks-0.14/lib/HTML/FormatText/WithLinks.pm)

Setting the `after_link` option to, say, " (%l)" will put the link in line after the anchor text. In your example you would get `Microsoft (http://www.microsoft.com)`.

Comment: I saw this module it insert the links at the end as footnotes ,is it possible also to to keep the link in its position ?

Comment: The second example in the Synopsis shows how to do it (the example has the URL in brackets, but it doesn't have to be).

Comment: Yes you can put the link in line. I have modified my answer to explain.